# mysqldump error when running from powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, mysql

I have a script containing the following...

```
$conn = "C:\Program Files\xxx xxx\xxx xxx\MySQLConfig\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump.exe"

$sqlargs = @("--verbose", "--user=xxx", "--password=xxx", "--port=xxx", "--add-drop-database", "--routines", "--single-transaction", "--databases", "xxx")

$bak_file = "C:\backups\bak040312.sql"

$log_file = "C:\backups\logs\L040312.log"

(&$conn $sqlargs | out-file bak_file -Encoding UTF8) 2>>$log_file
```

I have used echoargs to determine that my arguments are being passed properly to the exe

```
PS C:\scripts> echoargs $sqlargs
Arg 0 is <--verbose>
Arg 1 is <--user=xxx>
Arg 2 is <--password=xxx>
Arg 3 is <--port=xxx>
Arg 4 is <--add-drop-database>
Arg 5 is <--routines>
Arg 6 is <--single-transaction>
Arg 7 is <--databases>
Arg 8 is <xxx>
```

The backup seems to run as expected however mysqldump is throwing an error right after connecting to the mysql server.

```
mysqldump.exe : -- Connecting to localhost...
At line:1 char:3
+ (& <<<< $mysqlconn $sqlargs | out-file $bak_file -Encoding UTF8) 2>>$log_file
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (-- Connecting to localhost...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

-- Retrieving table structure for table agentactivity...
...
...
...
...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Disconnecting from localhost...
```

I've tried invoke-expression instead of &... I can't figure out why I am receiving this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
My goal is to have the verbose output and the errors from mysqldump in a log file.

Thanks

Comment: I see you're echoargs.exe from PSCX (+1).  Try running the PSCX command Resolve-ErrorRecord right after the line that fails.  This might give you a bit more useful info on this error.  Although it looks like the EXE might be crashing. Does this command work from the PowerShell prompt?

Comment: The script and the command run from the PowerShell prompt produce the same results. When I try to run Resolve-ErrorRecord from the prompt I receive the error: is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...

Comment: Did not have Pscx imported correctly... Now I just have to figure out what all this output from Resolve-ErrorRecord means

Comment: Side note: `Invoke-Expression` never helps in situations like this. It just adds a layer of indirection and causes all people who have to read the script to scratch their head why on earth you'd need an `eval` there.